# Google Analytics API - Can I use my own Google account to show reports to others?

Tags: python, openssl, rsa, google-analytics-api

My client operates a website that implements Google Analytics (tracking).

She would like to report a few core statistics to stakeholders (pageviews).

The stakeholders should not have access to my clients Google (Analytics) account.

Is it possible to use Google Analytics API to report to users that are **not** signed in with their own Google account?

**UPDATE / SOLVED**

I found that the easiest way to implement this is to get a "bearer" access token using python.
All you need is a Google service account and a private key (APIs & auth > Credentials).
Have your javascript client request the access token from your server and use the [gapi.auth.setToken](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthsetToken) method to authorize. Now you can call methods like [gapi.client.analytics.management.accounts.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api).

Note: you do need to activate the Analytics API in de [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) and I also had to create a PEM-file using [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html) in order to get the rsa module to accept the key.

Here's the python code I use (simplified).

```
from os import path
import base64
import rsa
import json
import calendar
import datetime
import urllib
iat = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.utcnow().utctimetuple())
exp = iat + 3600
header = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9" # {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}
claimset = {
   'iss': "MY_DEVELOPER_ACCOUNT@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
   'scope': "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly",
   'aud': "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
   'exp': exp,
   'iat': iat
}
claimset = json.dumps(claimset).encode('utf-8')
claimset = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(claimset)
signature = "%s.%s" % (header, claimset)
signature = rsa.sign(signature.encode('utf-8'), rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(open(PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY).read(), format='PEM'), 'SHA-256')
signature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature)
postdata = {
   'grant_type': "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
   'assertion': "%s.%s.%s" % (header, claimset, signature)
}
response = json.loads(urllib.urlopen("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", urllib.urlencode(postdata)).read())
print response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

By adding the service account email to your clients Google analytics account as a user just give it simple read access.  You will then be able to use the Service account to access the Google Analytics API and display the stats your customer wants.  No login required and they will only be able to see the information you choose to rip out of the Google Analytics API.

Comment: It took me some time to figure all of this out, it's working like a charm now, tnx again!